# Hibernate SessionFactory can't initialize from WEB app that runs in an AWS EC2 instance but runs ok from laptop

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hibernate, amazon-ec2

I have created an RDS DataBase in AWS which I can access successfully via HEIDI SQL from both: my laptop and an ec2 windows instance in AWS.
I run my web app from my laptop and it can access that DB successfully.
Then I run Glassfish in the ec2 instance and deploy my web app there using the same configuration I use in my laptop. I get the following:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean viewBean
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeBegin(HeadRenderer.java:70)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:865)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting invoke lifecycle  method public void View.ViewBean.init()
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:231)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting invoke lifecycle  method public void View.ViewBean.init()
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokeLifecycleMethod(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:393)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:306)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:229)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokeLifecycleMethod(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:376)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor259.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider$2.run(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:382)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class Model.U_HibernateUtil
    at Model.ModelBean.incNumSessions(ModelBean.java:2785)
    at Controller.Controller.newSession(Controller.java:44)
    at View.ViewBean.init(ViewBean.java:96)
    ... 58 more
```

The RDS DB uses MySQL Community.
In my Laptop I have MySQL 5.7.
The web app was made with Netbeans 8.2 on windows 10.
The Hibernate version is 4.3.1

here is the code that breaks:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Model;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory
 * object.
 *
 * @author usuario
 */
public class U_HibernateUtil {

  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  private static StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistry;

  static {
    try {
      // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml)
      // config file.
      Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
      configuration.configure();
      serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
      .applySettings(
        configuration.getProperties() );

      sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
      .buildSessionFactory( serviceRegistry.build() );

    }
    catch( HibernateException ex ) {
      // Log the exception.
      System.err.println( "Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex );
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError( ex );
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }

}
```

Thank you very much for any hint on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I was using: localhost:8080/MyWEBApp to initiate my app.
I discovered that I should have used ec2amaz-vc114rd:8080/MyWEBApp instead.

I went to localhost:4848 and saw that ther was a button to "launch" the application. When I clicked it, it gave me the link I needed.